# Is it possible to inject a external actionscript to a .swf file already on the web and then attach a flash vars to the original .swf file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm thinking of working on a script to block/ hide certain asset ID's from appearing inside a pre-existing .swf file on a website by utilising flash vars but I need to know am I able to add a new flash vars through an external script, I'd assume actionscript3?

Thanks

Comment: No. Unless the said SWF is specifically programmed to take custom external parameters, it works like a black box and won't let you modify its data. Simply, FlashVars go to a special object container, Flash application **can** access it, if it is programmed so, or won't notice it, if it isn't.

Comment: I see, thank you for your comment. :)